# Не запускается скрипт upstart. Debian 8

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, hosting

Доброго времени суток! Господа, первый раз столкнулся с Linux, в частности с Debian 8 - купил хостинг. Тестовый сайт на `nodejs` залил по пути `/srv/test`. Файл сервера `app.js`. Если запускаю напрямую (через PuTTy) `node app.js` - сайт  работает. Но, после закрытия PuTTy - отключается.

Пытаюсь написать (а точнее скопировать из инета https://www.8host.com/blog/sistema-inicializacii-upstart-chto-eto-takoe-i-kak-eto-rabotaet/) файл конфигурации для `upstart`. Ничего не получается - скрипт не хочет стартовать. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, в чем проблема. Кто, чем может). Файл `nodeTest.conf`:

```
description "Service for a test node.js server"
author "Vania Ivanov"
start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on shutdown
script

    export HOME="/srv/test" 
    echo $$ > /var/run/nodetest.pid
    exec /usr/bin/node  /srv/test/app.js
    // нюанс: по пути "/usr/bin/" файла "node" или "nodejs" нет
    // тоже самое и для пути "/usr/sbin/"; "/usr/locla/bin/"

end script
pre-start script

    echo "[`date`] Node Test pre-start" >> /var/log/nodetest.log

end script
post-start script

    echo "[`date`] Node Test post-start" >> /var/log/nodetest.log

    echo "[`date`] Node Test post-start" >> /var/log/nodetest.log

end script
pre-stop script

    echo "[`date`] Node Test pre-stop" >> /var/log/nodetest.log
    rm /var/run/nodetest.pid

end script
```

После перезагрузки сервера скрипт пытается стартовать, как я понимаю, 2 раза. В какой-то момент я добавил событие `post-start`. Файл `nodetest.log`.

```
[Tue Jan 23 12:36:02 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 12:36:04 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 12:45:14 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 12:45:15 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:04:19 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:04:20 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:15:25 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:15:26 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:22:26 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:22:27 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:26:50 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:26:51 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:29:35 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:29:36 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:33:46 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:33:47 EET 2018] Node Test Starting
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:37 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start //в этом моменте я добавил событие "post-start" и поменял подпись
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:37 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:38 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:38 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:46:08 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:46:08 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:46:09 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:46:09 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:16:09 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:16:09 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:31:46 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:31:46 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:33:12 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:33:12 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:33:13 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 14:33:13 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
```

Команда `find / -name node` выдает:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/include/node
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/share/doc/node
/proc/irq/44/node
/proc/irq/43/node
/proc/irq/42/node
/proc/irq/41/node
/proc/irq/40/node
/proc/irq/15/node
/proc/irq/14/node
/proc/irq/13/node
/proc/irq/12/node
/proc/irq/11/node
/proc/irq/10/node
/proc/irq/9/node
/proc/irq/8/node
/proc/irq/7/node
/proc/irq/6/node
/proc/irq/5/node
/proc/irq/4/node
/proc/irq/3/node
/proc/irq/2/node
/proc/irq/1/node
/proc/irq/0/node
/sys/bus/node
/sys/devices/system/node
```

П.С: в файле конфигурации, строку `exec /usr/bin/node` заменил на `exec /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/node` (здесь находится исполняющий файл Ноды)- согласно логу скрипт пытался загрузится всего 1 раз. Что это может значить?

П.П.С: Перегрузил сервер, команда `ps ax | grep node` выдала:

```
208 pts/1    Ssl+   0:00 /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/node /srv/test/app.js
 1587 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep node
// при этом в файле конфигурации путь указан "exec /root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.9.0/bin/node"
```

Изменил путь в файле конфигурации на `exec /usr/bin/node`, перегрузил - команда `ps ax | grep node` выдала:

```
1581 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep node
```

Команда `cat /var/log/messages | grep node` оба раза выдала одно и тоже:

```
Binary file (standard input) matches
```

Запустил сервер Ноды в ручную `node app.js`, команда `ps ax | grep node` выдала:

```
 1864 pts/1    Sl+    0:00 node app.js
 2130 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep node
```

Comment: В дебиане же нету upstart

Comment: @andreymal, я установил. Ну, и вроде, как - он запускается. Сейчас буду добывать инфо, как сказано в ответе Sergey'я

Comment: Зачем upstart в дебиане, лучше systemd сразу изучайте :)

Comment: @andreymal, когда изучал вопрос запуска сервера Nodejs, все время попадал на `upstart`. `Systemd` попался лишь раз, да и то, когда уже `upstart` не получилось настроить. Буду иметь ввиду Ваш коммент, но пока еще надеюсь на сообщество `StackOverflow` )

Comment: Насколько я помню, upstart умер, и все дистрибутивы, кто его использовали, переходят на systemd, поэтому про него и пишу) Ещё есть вариант supervisord использовать, субъективно он попроще будет

Comment: @andreymal, нашел утилиту `pm2` npmjs.com/package/pm2. Она сама создает нужные файлы для автоматического запуска сервера, при перезагрузке. Если я правильно понял, она как раз через `systemd` работает.

Answer (score 1):

> Если запускаю напрямую (через PuTTy) node app.js - сайт работает. Но,
>   после закрытия PuTTy - отключается.

Это естественное поведение системы. Когда вы через putty заходите на сервер, создаётся сессия, в рамках которой Вы запускаете программы. Вы вышли из putty - сессия закрылась, ядро прибило все процессы, запущенные в рамках этой сессии.

Совершенно неправильный, но наглядный способ это победить - запустить Ваш сервер так:

```
node app.js &
```

Обратите внимание на символ '&' в конце строки. Он обязывает *shell* после запуска *node* отсоединить (!) этот процесс от сессии. Теоретически, он должен остаться, после завершения сессии. Но не всегда это прокатит.

> скрипт не хочет стартовать

Как же он не хочет стартовать, когда в логе я вижу:

```
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:38 EET 2018] Node Test pre-start
[Tue Jan 23 13:43:38 EET 2018] Node Test post-start
```

Скрипт - стартует! Так как сообщения

```
Node Test pre-stop
```

Мы не видим, то это означает, *node* не помер. А почему Вы предположили, что *node* так и не запустился?  Попробуйте выдать команду (в putty):

```
ps ax | grep node
```

И посмотрите, что будет на выходе. Есть смысл посмотреть лог-файл (не знаю, где он у вас конкретно расположен) что-то типа:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep node
```

Я имею в виду не *nodetest.log*, а системный лог.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, я посмотрел инфо, как Вы сказали - обновил вопрос. Полученная информация, мне, конечно же, ни о чем не говорит)

Comment: Sergey, еще раз спасибо за внимание. Я нашел утилиту `pm2` https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2. Она сама создает нужные файлы для автоматического запуска сервера, при перезагрузке. Боюсь, конечно, сглазить, но проблема вроде бы решена. В глобальном смысле. В `upstart` уже нет необходимости.

Comment: Ну так это - хорошо! Если есть специальный инструмент - надо им пользоваться!